# Eclipse: CDT Code Analysis for Git Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Photon. I imported a Git project and want to apply CDT code analysis for this project, but I don't have the option:

[image]

For a new c project, I have:

[image: New c project]

For Pydev projects I can choose "set as source folder" but I can't find something similar for c projects. Does anybody know?

Comment: How did you import the git project?

Comment: For import I used the git view, then: close a git repository -> clone URI -> URI = https://github.com/WLANThermo-nano/WLANThermo_nano_Software -> select all branches -> Local destination, Finish. Then I have it in my git view. Right click on it -> Import Project, Finish. Then I have it in my C Perspective

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the Eclipse CDT project metadata files (`.project`., `.cproject`) are not checked into the repository?